# Using image attachment only from gallery

Tags: java, android-studio

My team using plugin from https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper for Image Attachment so after input image (whether it from Camera or Gallery) it can automatically redirect to Crop the selected Image.

Is there any way for disabled Camera Input for Image attachment, so it only attached the image only from gallery and other sources but not from Camera (by disabling or hide the option)? I've been searching the option for disabled the Camera menu, but nothing comes out of it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own image chooser, then pass in the selected Uri.

you can refer to https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3487 for more examples.

the specific code to use is here: -

```
// start cropping activity for pre-acquired image saved on the device
CropImage.activity(imageUri)
 .start(this);
```